# Javascript str.replace with a RegEx and replacement string (not a function) to convert a DNA string to its complement?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace

Is there a way to use a javascript `str.replace` with a regular expression (RegEx) only to convert a DNA string to its (reverse) complement sequence?

This is a follow up to another question I asked about DNA complementary sequence conversion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33335650/are-these-javascript-dna-complement-algorithms-equivalent-optimal). I am posting this separately because I am trying to learn more about Regular Expressions and how javascript works with them.

I found an answer to a similar question in [JavaScript Regular Expression Replace Multiple Letters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33288625/895065), but that question wasn't specifically asking for a RegEx and replacement string in lieu of a function as I am here.

Given a typical sequence of DNA bases as a string, the complement can be found by reversing the string, then performing the mapping of each base to its most energetically favorable hydrogen-bonding partner (A->T, T->A, C->G, G->C). For example, the complement of CTTAACCAGCGGACACGGGCTTGGC is GCCAAGCCCGTGTCCGCTGGTTAAG.

Here is one such algorithm in javascript given the reversed sequence `reverseSeq`:

```
complementSeq=reverseSeq.replace([/[ATCG]/g], function (match, p1, p2, p3, p4) {
            if (p1)
                return 'T';
            else if (p2)
                return 'A';
            else if (p3)
                return 'G';
            else if (p4)
                return 'C';
        }
        );
```

This script uses a function as the second argument to `.replace`. Could the same result be achieved with a new string as the call to `.replace`? If not, why not? Here is [some documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) on `string.replace` and the syntax for using matches in the new string argument. I looked into [conditional RegEx](http://www.regular-expressions.info/conditional.html) but don't see how it could be used for this purpose, i.e. telling `.replace` to use a `T` when it matches an `A`, etc.

Comment: You did not get an answer the last time you asked this?

Comment: I got some answers to the other question I asked, which is basically what is the most efficient javascript algorithm for complement DNA finding. None of these produced or seemed to consider the second question I asked about using RegEx with a replacement string in particular, so I separated the 2 questions.

Comment: I actually did just find an answer to this question in another question though: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33288625/895065. Maybe some of these similar questions should be merged or deleted/edited?

Comment: @jwco -- the "duplicate" question does not request reversal of the string... this is a different question IMO. It asks (maybe not clearly enough??) "given `GCAGGACTTTTTA`, can you provide the reversal _and complement_ string (`TAAAAAGTCCTGC`), using only string.replace with regex (_not a function_) -- I think the answer would be no - you must use a function (or other algorithm) to reverse the string.

Comment: Well, you would just replace the characters with their complimenting character, then reverse the string. See [this demo](http://jsbin.com/rudakeqofi/1/edit?js,console)

Comment: A simple for loop would probably be much faster.

Comment: @CodeJockey This is not to object to your hypothesis (clearly you know way more about RegEx than me) but this article makes me wonder: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3693698/how-does-this-regex-replacement-reverse-a-string

Comment: Hey, my demo is RegEx-ish. I don't understand what more you want, the demo provides the correct output does it not?

Comment: @TinyGiant - that is essentially in his other (linked) question. Using a map of replacements, and splitting/reversing/joining the string. Also, you can't get credit (if that's what you're after) by leaving a comment - only an answer - and this question was closed as a duplicate (though I still disagree, my voice is only so loud [and that's just fine])

Comment: @jwco -- though I haven't personally confirmed that the linked algorithm works, and though it does _appear_ to produce a single regex string that is then used for reversal,  I can see that it produces a regex expression which uses lookbehind. JavaScript (ECMAScript) regular expressions do not support lookbehind, so... I still think it's not possible with pure JS regex, but I COULD(?) indeed be wrong? It'll be nasty and probably need a few blog posts to go through, though, I predict :-)

Comment: @jwco -- upon closer inspection, I notice also that both look behinds in the final expression are variable-length, at least one of which looks necessary for the reversal functionality. among the languages that support look-behind, only a few support variable length look-behind. Java, last I checked, does not support non-finite-variable-length lookbehind, so I wonder if that example will run(?!) maybe recent versions?

Comment: @CodeJockey 1) I know, and 2) I've got 7k+ rep, so yeah I know.